# requiring a specific commit of a package - composer seems to be ignoring composer.json requirements

Tags: php, composer-php, octobercms, php-7.1

I have the following composer.json / require:

```
    "require": {
        "php": ">=7.0",
        "ext-mbstring": "*",
        "ext-openssl": "*",
        "october/rain": "1.0.443",
        "october/system": "1.0.443",
        "october/backend": "1.0.443",
        "october/cms": "1.0.443",
        "laravel/framework": "5.5.*",
        "wikimedia/composer-merge-plugin": "dev-master#06deb2de8fe46826bbd3880003d2aed1716658b3"
    },
```

The full composer.json can be found at https://pastebin.com/SXTeWHgC

I'm running:

- Composer 1.10.19 (since wikimedia/composer-merge-plugin doesn't work on Composer 2.0)
- PHP 7.1.33 (that's what the prod server has)

Anyway, when I do `composer update` I get the following

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Installation request for wikimedia/composer-merge-plugin dev-master#06deb2de8fe46826bbd3880003d2aed1716658b3 -> satisfiable by wikimedia/composer-merge-plugin[dev-master].
    - wikimedia/composer-merge-plugin dev-master requires php >=7.2.0 -> your PHP version (7.1.33) does not satisfy that requirement.
```

This doesn't make any sense to me. [wikimedia/composer-merge-plugin dev-master#06deb2de8fe46826bbd3880003d2aed1716658b3](https://github.com/wikimedia/composer-merge-plugin/blob/06deb2de8fe46826bbd3880003d2aed1716658b3/composer.json) doesn't require >= 7.2.0 - it requires >= 5.3.2. So why am I getting this error and what can I do about it?

Comment: Probably because of this: https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md#i-have-locked-a-dependency-to-a-specific-commit-but-get-unexpected-results-

Answer (score 2):

From composer documentation:

> **Note:** This feature has severe technical limitations, as the composer.json metadata will still be read from the branch name you specify before the hash. You should therefore only use this as a temporary solution during development to remediate transient issues, until you can switch to tagged releases. The Composer team does not actively support this feature and will not accept bug reports related to it.

<sup>*Source: https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#package-links*</sup>

This is totally aligned with the behaviour you are seeing, the *composer.json* of that library is red from the `dev-master` HEAD commit of the branch and not to the explicit commit reference.

Comment: I agree that it's a bad idea but it's OctoberCMS that's doing it. Like look at their latest tagged release: https://github.com/octobercms/october/blob/v1.1.1/composer.json#L46 has in it `"wikimedia/composer-merge-plugin": "dev-feature/composer-v2 as 1.5.0"`. They shouldn't be making tagged releases that have dev deps like that imho.

Comment: Not quite following your logic there. They are pointing to the HEAD of that branch, whatever it is dev or or another branch, how is it related to the question trying to reference a specific commit?

Comment: And FWIIW, the composer.json of OctoberCMS you are pointing at is also stating `"php": ">=7.2"`

Comment: I said "_like look at their latest tagged release_". Tagging HEAD of _any_ branch is a terrible idea imho because HEAD is not fixed in time. HEAD can change. What if they delete the branch? What if they make bc breaking changes to that branch or any other that they've tagged? Is it the version that I'm using? No. idk what version of OctoberCMS my composer.json is from. The point is that _even_ in their latest tagged release they're doing stuff that they have zero business doing imho.

Comment: `dev-feature/composer-v2 as 1.5.0` is not pointing to a specific git commit has, the version requirement from your question is

Comment: And if you think that the developers of that application are doing something wrong, you should better ask them about this, not us

Answer (score 0):

You could either use another branch, which you'd have to provide as your own fork (having `HEAD` reverted to exactly the one commit you want to use). Or you could realize that you're riding a dead horse and get off ...which means updating PHP, composer and just use the `composer20` branch. Your claim that `wikimedia/composer-merge-plugin` wouldn't work with composer 2.x is false.